# Text comparison in Excel - What formula should I be using and how to do it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have 2 sheets, the first sheet contains a coulm of Emails and the second sheet contains 2 columns ( Some Emails & Status). How to make excel get the status of each email from sheet 2 into sheet 1 accordingly! I tried everything; If, Vlockup, Match & Index, if ISNUMBER, but nothing seems to work!! I don't know if because the data is in text or I'm doing something wrong. Could anyone tell me the right formula for this query?

Again, I want to get the email status from sheet 2 into sheet 1 emails accordingly instead of searching one by one.

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVf2H.png)
[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si4fd.png)

Comment: Please show some example data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I attatched screenshots.

Comment: Attach Screenshots showing the column numbers **(A, B, C...)** so that we can make sense of what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: I edited the screenshots to show the column numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is **Sheet2** with some sample data:

[image: Sheet2 Data]

You want to lookup the Email IDs in Sheet2 and extract the corresponding Status from **Sheet2** to **Sheet1**.

Let's say this is how your **Sheet1** looks like:

[image: Sheet 1]

In the **Sheet1**, in cell B2, enter this formula: `=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$B$7, 2, 0)`. Replace Sheet2 in this formula with the name of your Sheet. Also, don't forget to change the cell references in the formula as per your requirements.

You'll get the status of the Email ID corresponding to Cell **B2** (which is fetched from **Sheet2**).

Drag down to fill other columns, and you'll end up with this:

[image: final data]

If you suspect that your data might have unwanted spaces, use this formula instead:
`=VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2), TRIM(Sheet2!$A$2:$B$7), 2, 0)` and press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. This will remove unwanted spaces in your data and give you the result.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work, unfortunately.
The 1 formula; =VLOOKUP(B,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$18,2,0) gives me invalid name error.
The 2 formula; =VLOOKUP(TRIM(B:B), TRIM(Sheet2!$A$2:$B$18),2,0) says value not available error.
It's driving me crazy

Comment: Are you sure you used the Formula 1 correctly? I mean you've mentioned here that you used ``=VLOOKUP(B,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$18,2,0)``. What does ``B`` mean here? It should reference to **a cell** not the **whole column**. Are the Email IDs in Sheet2 present in Column B and Status in Column C? If this is the case you're referencing to wrong cells. Can you give the screenshot along with the column numbers like I did?

Comment: I tried to reference to a cell instead of column B yet it gives me the same error #N/A (Value not available error).
My formula: =VLOOKUP(B102,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$18,2,0).
Could you plz tell me what am I doing wrong?
P.S. Screenshots attatched